# How to print a YEAR inside an input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

Is it possible to print the current year inside an input value with javascript?
PS.: I don't want to use the type="date" method.
PS. 2: The value needs to be printed on the input as soon as the screen is opened.

```js
var dateControl = document.querySelector('input.year[type="text"]');
dateControl.value = "getFullYear()";
```

```html
<input type="text" id="year" value="">
```

Comment: The linked duplicate shows you how to get the year.  Aside from that, your selector should simply be: `document.querySelector('#year')` since you can select on an `id`.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me, as I've already tried it.

Comment: Can you update the code shown to demonstrate that attempt and indicate what specifically isn't working?

Comment: Well, the published code should have the current year already printed inside the input and it does not appear.

Comment: try ` dateControl.value = new Date().getFullYear(); `

Comment: Do you want to show just the year of whatever the date was put in the field?

Comment: @Mari: Look at the linked duplicate again, and look at your code in the question above again.  Specifically the part where you use the string `"getFullYear()"` and where the linked duplicate uses the code `new Date().getFullYear()`.  Do you see the difference between those two things?

Comment: @Zlatko I want to show the current year, but the person can change if necessary.

Comment: @Mari: In short, when applying the information present in the linked duplicate, what happens when you just do this?: `document.getElementById('year').value = new Date().getFullYear();`

Comment: It worked! The problem was the fact in document.getElementById('year'). Thank you.